# Blogger - how to reduce min-height?

Tags: blogger

I recently changed my blogger commenting system to google+. I have a small issue that has to do with min-height, i'm pretty sure.

Here is a blog post: http://seriouslyfunnyhumor.blogspot.com/2014/01/wife-is-wife-no-matter-who-the-hell-you-are.html

If you scroll down you see that there is a big space between the google+ comment form and the homepage button.

I tried fixing it by inspecting element and inserting some CSS in my blog's HTML, but i failed to fix it. However, i can fix it when i inspect element, look at this picture:

http://s1275.photobucket.com/user/EasyPictrs/media/Bloggerheight_zps029767e1.gif.html

Look on the right where i inserted the arrow. If i change the min-height there, the problem gets fixed. But i can't find that part of code in my HTML, and i also didn't manage to find what CSS should i insert in my blog in order to fix this.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any space between the form and button. Is the problem solved?

Comment: Second link in your question says page deleted. What HTML change worked for you when on inspect mode?